# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext

Tags: java, servlets, spring-context

I get this exception when tried to create

> ApplicationContext applicationContext;

I have

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

also have this in my servlet

> import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

in my `pom.xml`, but still getting this msg. I tried `mvn.clean`

Answer (score 1):

You can create `ApplicationContext` by 2 ways

**1) XML based:**

`ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");`

Here `beans.xml` contains all the bean definitions.

**2) Annotations based:**

`ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ApplicationConfiguration.class);`

Here, `ApplicationConfiguration` is annotated with `@Configuration` annotation.

Also, please make sure that classpath has all the spring jars.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
package com.zoltanraffai;  
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;  
import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean; 
import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;

public class HelloWorldApp{ 
   public static void main(String[] args) { 
      ApplicationContext context=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml"); 
      HelloWorld obj = (HelloWorld) context.getBean("helloWorld");    
      obj.getMessage();    
   }
}
```

https://dzone.com/articles/difference-between-beanfactory-and-applicationcont